# Terminal not responding

Tags: command-line, webp

I'm new to Linux and am having weird problems. For instance, when I try to use the terminal I can't get it to follow my commands. Instead of doing what it's asked to do it sends me to the manual where I haven't been able to see my problems described: I can't in the least make it work!
One of the problems I'm trying to solve is my system being drenched with webp-images even though I save my images in jpg/jpeg.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please include an example of a command you execute, and what output you get? Your question probably needs a little more detail before anyone can provide qualified help. Thanks!

Comment: Please also provide your Ubuntu product & release details  (this is a Ubuntu Q&A site; with SE *Unix & Linux* supporting Linux questions).

Comment: Try to express clearly what you attempt to do, what you expect to happen and what happens instead. Use "Edit" to update your question and make it more clear.

Comment: Well, I'm quite new to Linux so I meet some weird problems. However, this one takes the cake: The terminal doesn't react to my commands. I've put up a new profile without solving the problem, my password isn't recognized, and it seems to have frozen completely. As I simply have to do something about my pictures being turned from jpeg, etc. into webp it's very importatn that I get the terminal to work.

Comment: Given we have no idea what Ubuntu product, or release you're using, we're very limited in what help we can provide. For some products, removing or changing the default `python3` version can cause certain terminals (*that rely on python3 to operate*) from working, but given we have no actual information from you - we cannot know what details can apply.